# MVVM Expose List from Model to ViewModel and View

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a model which currently looks through a series of different log files and then makes an object for each item in those files and appends them to a list (ListOfLogs). Once the model is done parsing the log files it does a property changed event to notify the VM that the ListOfLogs is ready.

The Viewmodel then handles the property changed event and creates an ObservableCollection from the model's ListOfLogs. The view then binds to that observablecollection.

Now that I have switched from an ObservableCollection to a ICollectionView I get an invalid operation exception since the calling thread doesn't own ListOfLogs object. This makes me thing that the way I expose the List is not following the MVVM pattern

Added Code:
ViewModel.cs:

```
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    #region Fields

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Properties

    public Model myModel { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> collectionView { get; set; }

    #endregion // Properties

    #region Constructor

    public ViewModel() {
        myModel = new Model();
        myModel.PropertyChanged += propertyChanged;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    #endregion // Constructor

    #region Methods

    private void propertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
        switch (e.PropertyName ) {
            case "Objects":
                // Is there a better way to do this

                collectionView = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(myModel.Objects);

                //
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("collectionView"));
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("No case for {0}, ", e.PropertyName));
                break;
        }
    }
```

Model.cs:
Edit: fixed mistake when invoking the property changed event

```
namespace TestApp1 {
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged {

    #region Fields

    private IList<MyObject> _Objects;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Properties

    public IList<MyObject> Objects { get => _Objects ?? (_Objects = new List<MyObject>()); private set { if (Objects != value) _Objects = value; } }

    #endregion // Properties

    #region Constructor

    public Model() {

    } 

    #endregion // Constructor

    #region Methods

    public void LoadObjects() {
        // Parse through files normally for now just junk works
        Parallel.For(0, 10000, dostuff => {
            var myOb = new MyObject(){ dt = DateTime.Now, message = "Message" };
            lock (Objects) {
                Objects.Add(myOb);
            }
        });
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Objects"));
    }

    #endregion // Methods

}

public class MyObject {
    public DateTime dt { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string stuff1 { get; set; }
    public string stuff2 { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: can you add the relevant, minimal, code for which you need help ?

Comment: @ManojChoudhari I wrote something up real quick and added a comment to what I'm asking about in the ViewModel.cs::propertyChanged method. The View is just a datagrid bounded to the property in the VM

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are modifying the Objects list while passing it to the constructor of the observable collection. (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs,cfaa9abd8b214ecb in the constructor where "copyfrom")

The InvalidOperationException belongs to your Objects.Add() call in the Parallel.For.

```
private void CopyFrom(IEnumerable<T> collection)
        {
            IList<T> items = Items;
            if (collection != null && items != null)
            {
                using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
                {
                    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
                    {
                        items.Add(enumerator.Current);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In the delegate of Parallel.For you are using a lock. You could use this as well for the property changed event:

```
                    lock(myModel.Objects)
                    {

                    collectionView = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>(myModel.Objects);
                    }
```

Or add the event raising to the lock in the Parallel.For delegate

```
lock (Objects)
                    {
                        Objects.Add(myOb);
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Objects"));
                    }
```

Or you could just wait until all items are read and then raise one property changed event after completing the Parallel.For.

Comment: My bad, it seems when I was writting this up I made a mistake on where I raise the Property changed event. On the actual code I call the property changed event outside of the parallel for like you suggested. I still get the same invalid operation exception, but only when using an ICollectionView instead of an ObservableCollection. Otherwise the ObservableCollection doesn't throw any exceptions